# making the phone number the most visible

Tags: user-behavior, conversion, conversion-rate, phone-numbers

So my e-commerce site has a freephone number. I was just wondering if we could work out all the best ways to get more people to ring that number, as orders always convert better and are of more value when the phone rings, rather than email. So lets think of ways to increase phone conversions:

1. I am using a freephone number, does anyone have any experience on what converts better, a local number or a freephone? I assumed freephone as it makes you look more credible, thus more trustworthy, and thus more likely to order. But I guess a local number might convey a feeling of a company that is local - or at least a country you feel comfortable with.
2. I have placed my phone number in the top right corner of the header. Now I know the golden triangle is of great importance, and where a visitor will look first, but I felt that people expect it more to be on the top right, and the logo needs to be in the left. Although has anyone tried the logo on the right, and phone on the left?
3. I like to have an icon next to the phone, to make it more obvious to attract the users attention. I use an icon of a traditional looking phone, but these days you see people use smartphone icons. Any idea what helps more?
4. You hear that people are attracted to faces, not only that, but the user will also look at what the face is looking at. So if I have a face look at the phone number, will that also help increase conversions?
5. Call of action text, is there a good call of action that helps increase conversions? Such as Call Us Now, Speak with an engineer, Get a free consultation, Our salespeople are standing by, etc. Anyone know if a COA can help increase conversions.
6. I am using a 24px size font so its reasonably large. What are your thoughts on different size fonts?

If anyone else has any other suggestions on how to better increase people ringing the phone from your site, then please mention them also.

Comment: I am surprised that phone orders are better than web orders - do you think there might be some issue with your checkout process on your e-commerce site?

Comment: Its B2B people seem more comfortable ordering on the phone when its over $1000.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions if you desperately want calls from users:

- You can try putting the freephone number under the photograph/picture
  in the product details page.
- You can try putting the freephone number underneath the search results page/listing pages e.g. There are 60 results for T-Shirt, please call XYZ for help finding the correct product.
- You can put the number underneath the main call to actions like (Buy Button/Save button)